# Error importing firebase-admin

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I was trying to create custom tokens using the Firebase Admin SDK. But while importing `import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';` as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

I got an error `process.binding is not supported`.

I'm using

- `browserify`: `14.0.0`
- `firebase`: `^3.6.8`
- `firebase-admin`: `^4.1.0`

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using browserify and `import` syntax instead of the [node.js module `require` syntax](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), it sounds like you're trying to use the Firebase Admin SDK in the browser.  The admin SDK is only for use on a server, and is not for end-user access (see the warning at the top of the [Add the Firebase Admin SDK to your Server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) page).

If you are trying to use the JavaScript SDK for end-user access, follow [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) instead.

If you are using this on a node.js server, try using the `require` syntax instead:

`var admin = require("firebase-admin");`

Comment: `var admin = require("firebase-admin");` didn't help. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I'm using React + Firebase

Comment: As I said in my answer above, the Firebase Admin SDK is meant to only be used on a server, not in the browser. Can you explain why you are trying to use it with React?

For an excellent guide to getting started with React + Firebase, check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwNATxfUsgI).

Comment: I was trying to setup OAuth using Github and persist the login on refresh by saving the token in localStorage. For persisting login, I needed a custom token to sign in with the custom token and to create a custom token, I was using the Firebase SDK.

Comment: Is there any way to get token for logged in user? Previously, we could do something like `authData.token` but now we get something like `authData.credential.accessToken` which shows as an invalid custom token by Firebase.

Comment: You can use the Firebase web SDK to sign in to Github once you enable Github as a sign in method in the "Authentication" section of your Firebase console.

For the absolute easiest answer, I suggest using the excellent Firebase-UI https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#using-firebaseui-for-authentication

Here is a guide with some more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/github-auth

Answer (score 0):

I am using Webpack for a Node application which uses `firebase-admin`. The solution seemed to be to set `target` in the Webpack configuration file to `'node'`.